# Steps to transfer file from One Windows Remote Server to another Windows Remote Server using OS Process Sampler in JMeter

Tags: ssh, process, jmeter

I have transferred or copied a files from local machine to Server successfully using OS Process Sampler but unable to transfer a file from One remote server to another remote server on windows.

Can anyone explain me the process or share the steps or command which are being used to do the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have [OpenSSH servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview) on both machines you can use [SSH Command](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) sampler to execute [scp command](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-scp-command-to-securely-transfer-files/)  for transferring a file from one remote machine to another remote machine

[image]

In case of Windows you might have to provide the full path to scp.exe binary like:

```
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe
```

The exact configuration may differ depending on source/destination paths, whether [public key authentication](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/public-key-authentication) is enabled or not, etc.

Also SSH Command sampler doesn't come with JMeter, you will need to install it as a part of **SSH Protocol Support** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]